# Get all field names(attributes) from DynamoDB using amazion java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Amazon SDK.

My requirement is to fetch all the field names(attributes) from DynamoDB cloud and print it on the console.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a mapper (similar to Hibernate in relational databases) which is a layer over the client.

This is the official page: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3756417425850538

Besides, when you create the tables in the console, you must define the indexes (hash, range, local, global or range index) and whether to project all attributes or only some.